# convert int to string pointer C

Tags: c

> Write a function the gets two strings and number, the signiture of the function: `void get_formated_integer(char *format, char *result, int num)` the function convert the given number `num` according the `format` and returns a string in the variable `result`, for `%b` converts int to binary of the number, for example, for the call: `get_formated_integer("%b",&result, 18);` then `*result` will get the string `10010`

My code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
  void convert_binary(int num)//converts decimal number to binary
{
    if(num>0)
    {
    convert_binary(num/2);
    printf("%d", num%2);
    }

}

void get_formated_integer(char *format, char *result, int num)
{
    if(format[1]=='b')
      convert_binary(num);
}

int main()
{
    char result[100];
    get_formated_integer("%b",&result, 18);
}
```

My output:

`10010`

> I don't understand how to do that `*result` will get the string `10010`
>
> sorry about my English

Comment: Why are you throwing away the result from `convert_binary`

Comment: @EdHeal I edited

Comment: You need to add code to write characters into the result array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, replace

```
void convert_binary(int num)//converts decimal number to bi
```

with

```
void convert_binary(int num, char * result) //converts decimal number to binary
```

for the sake to have a place (`result`) for storing the result.

---

Second, replace its body - recursive calling and direct printing

```
{
    if(num>0)
    {
    convert_binary(num/2);
    printf("%d", num%2);
    }
}
```

with

```
{
    static int i = 0;              // Offset in result for storing the current digit
    if(num>0)
    {
        convert_binary(num/2, result);
        sprintf(result+i, "%d", num % 2);
        ++i;
    } else 
        i = 0;
}
```

i.e. with statements for recursive call (updated function) and storing partial values.

---

Third, following previous changes, replace your original definition

```
void get_formated_integer(char *format, char *result, int num)
{
    if(format[1]=='b')
      convert_binary(num);
}
```

with

```
void get_formated_integer(char *format, char *result, int num)
{
    if(format[1]=='b')
        convert_binary(num, result);       // Only this is different
}
```

---

Four, put at the end in your `main()` function the statement for printing the result (as we changed direct printings in recursive calls to storing):

```
    printf("%s\n", result);
```

Comment: Is the use of a static int a good idea - makes the function can only be used once!`

Comment: Also will the result be in reverse order?

Comment: @EdHeal - In your first comment you were right - I forget reinitialize it, thanks! **I corrected my answer.** (Emphasized for OP).

Comment: @EdHeal - In your second command: The answer to your question is "no". Result is in the correct order.

Comment: @EdHeal - You are right again. My goal was to keep the original OP code and insert as few changes as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`result` is a pointer to a memory region. I will try to provide a short explanation, you will find more about pointers [here](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2014/readings/pointers.pdf) (and I strongly suggest you read this tutorial).

When you declare `char result[100]` you allocate a memory region for 100 characters. A pointer is a variable that has as value a memory address, so you can change the values at a memory address. Basically, what your function should do is to make a string with the formatted number and place it at the memory address indicated by `result`.